# Does hydrogen bonding only occur between water molecules?

Tags: water, hydrogen-bond

Does hydrogen bonding only occur between water molecules?

Is the dipole-dipole intermolecular interaction know as hydrogen bonding because it is between water molecules, or is called that because of the hydrogen molecules present in the bond?

Comment: A quick check of Wikipedia reveals: "A hydrogen bond is the electrostatic attraction between polar molecules that occurs when a hydrogen (H) atom bound to a highly electronegative atom such as nitrogen (N), oxygen (O) or fluorine (F) experiences attraction to some other nearby highly electronegative atom. The name hydrogen bond is something of a misnomer, as it is not a true bond but a particularly strong dipole-dipole attraction, and should not be confused with a covalent bond."  We're okay with elementary questions here, but it's best to take the available information and ask

Comment: about a conceptual issue related to what you don't understand about the existing material.

Comment: That wikipedia explanation above is somewhat imprecise/outdated/slightly obsolete https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88866/17952

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NO**, Water is not only the example for hydrogen bonding. It's most common example for basics.

Hydrogen bonds occur in DNA, proteins, polymers, etc. But for introductory level it is easy to explain with water.

**DNA:** Hydrogen bonding between guanine and cytosine, one of two types of base pairs in DNA.

[image]

**Polymer:** Para-aramid structure

[image]

---

Images: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_bond)